# Error: jkerrguestadmin@gmail.com is an invalid From email address

Tags: trailhead, case-auto-response

I am facing the below error: I am doing **"Add an Auto-Response Rule"** from the link : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/service_basics/units/service_basics_automate_case_management

[image]

I have the following users list.

[image]

**That particular user is updated::**

[image]

**When I tried to create the new user I get the below error, wonder??**

[image]

Comment: The user you are highlighting cannot be your user, as it is an inactive one. Also, the username is not important, the email is.

Comment: @Robin - I make that user active. Still same error. Please see updates in post above

Comment: Please see my comment then as well: the error message clearly says it needs to be **your** user's **email address**.

Comment: Are you saying that I need to create normal/new user and user his/her email id ? Please confirm

Comment: Salesforce is saying exactly what email addresses you can use in its error message. You are highlighting a **username** of **another** user,  which are both irrelevant.

Comment: @Robin - Thanx, but any other email id not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation here (https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_auto_response_rules.htm&language=en_US): Enter the email address to include on the From line of the auto-response message. This must be either one of your verified organization-wide email addresses or the email address in your Salesforce user profile, and must be different from the routing addresses you use for Email-to-Case.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check that the email is already activated on **Organization-Wide Email Addresses**

After that you verify the email, you can use it for the Case Auto-Response Rule

Comment: how does this differ from the already provided answer?